# ExpressJs is return error `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` if I import the file without `js` extension

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I build a expressJs app by ES6 and I got the below error:

```
(node:4132) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\wamp64\www\myDemos\nodeJs\expressJsExample\config\app' imported from E:\wamp64\www\myDemos\nodeJs\expressJsExample\server.mjs
←[90m    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:255:11)←[39m
←[90m    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:603:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:644:13)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:94:40)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:240:28)←[39m
←[90m    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)←[39m
←[90m    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If I use `import app from './config/app.js';` then working but if I use `import app from './config/app';` then return the above error.

The below is my code:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ExpressJsExample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Express Js Example",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "Mukesh Singh Thakur",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chalk": "^4.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "http-errors": "^1.7.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "pg": "^8.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
import http from 'http';
import app from './config/app';

const server = http.Server(app);
server.listen(3000, () => {
       return true;
});
```

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

export default app;
```

The example app is available in `https://github.com/msthakur08/express-js-example` URL. The example files import with '.js' existence but I want to import file without '.js' existence.

Comment: I am using ES6.

Comment: what is your node version ?

Comment: any solution? i got same issue

Answer (score 84):

You can resolve this by:
Just add js as an extension to file

Before:

```js
import std from './route/student'
```

After:

```js
import std from './route/student.js'
```

Comment: Order of the arguments actually matter!!!!

Comment: Solved it. What does this mean?

Answer (score 52):

If someone is still searching, I got this error using node version 15, I was importing the files without the `.js` file extension, adding that fixed my issue.

Comment: Kind of lame that editors/IDE's auto import without the .js extension. Good to know though. I always thought it did not make a difference.

Comment: SyntaxError: Named export 'Request' not found - ExpressJS

Answer (score 20):

You can add this to your package json

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js"
},
```

Comment: Hey, I've added this but nothing helped

Comment: make sure you use the appropriate name of your entry point

Comment: (node:4132) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Comment: check this out, https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32103

Comment: It only working when you use nodemon. When use command "node index.js" then error still happen.

Comment: SyntaxError: Named export 'Request' not found - ExpressJS

Answer (score 9):

I solved this with this approach:-

When You are using Es6 import/export functionality with node, you need to import modules with `".mjs" extension`and before importing rename your module  `./path-to/app.js to ./path-to/app.mjs`

and change your code to this

```
import http from 'http';
import app from './config/app.mjs'; //.mjs extension is necessary

const server = http.Server(app);
server.listen(3000, () => {
       return true;
});
```

and run your app.js with `node --experimental-modules app.js`

more on this https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, and it got resolved when i removed the `type:"module"` from package.json

Comment: If you remove "type":"module" from the package.json you will not be able to use imports in your node environment

Comment: import/export only work if you set type to "module"

Answer (score 3):

As example `import 'express'` is resolved  as `./node_modules/express/index.js`.

In your case, create a folder called **app** with an index.js inside of it. After that you can import or require it using this line:

```
import app from './app/'
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by below steps

1. Install `esm` library
2. Removed the `type:"module"` from package.json
3. Added below command in package.json

   `"scripts": {"start": "nodemon -r esm app/index.js"}`

It's working for node 14 version

Answer (score 2):

I am using ts-node this way and works. Config `["type": "module"]` in package.json, then update tsconfig.json to [ts-node's ESM support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#native-ecmascript-modules) and pass the loader flag to node in scripts, `node --loader ts-node/esm ./index.ts`. tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "module": "ESNext", // ES2020
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "esm": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: adding `ts-node. experimentalSpecifierResolution` works for me

Comment: start using `npx tsx`, and stop using ts-node and fiddle useless and confusing tsconfig.sjon

Answer (score 1):

try changing the type using common,
so import is changed to require

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  //...
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you used "type": "module", on package.json and then you should use import. while you are using import it required default so in router or related required file you must use like "export default serverRouter"

Or can follow the below syntax:

```
import express from "express"
const serverRouter = express.Router()

serverRouter.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.send("hello I'm runnig 4000")
})

export default serverRouter
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two version of Node `v16.15.1` and `v14.20.1`.
It was giving an Error in Node v14.20.1.

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
```

Solved it by switching to Node v16.15.1.

`nvm use 16.15.1` # To switch to Node v16

`nvm ls` # Lists available Node versions

Answer (score 0):

if you are using es6 then your have to import all the file with file type

import app from './config/app.js';

not like

import app from './config/app';

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of NodeJs you should import files with .Js extension otherwise it will facing the same error.
I was facing the same issue when I import all files with .js then now it working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your project is based on typescript / nodejs and you want:

- your file extensions to be `.ts`
- To use ES6 module import/export (instead of commonjs modules)
- Not to add `.js` at the end of the module path

For example:

```
import x from "./y"
```

Instead of:

```
import x from "./y.js"
```

The complete config should be something like this:

1. `package.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts" 
     //make sure to use your own path to main file 
  },
}
```

2. `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Then you can run your project with:
`npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

I started using `npx tsx` and removed tsconfig.json and everything just works for me.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this error:

```
code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
```

It's typically saying there is a need for an extension for ./bin/www file.

what you have to do is:
add   `"type": "module", to your package.js`on
and rename .bin/www to ./bin/www.js
Restart your server

Answer (score -2):

node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\projetos2\data-base-with-node\src\routes\index' imported from C:\projetos2\data-base-with-node\src\server.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:418:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:983:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1080:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:40)    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Comment: import mainRouter from '../src/routes/index';

Comment: o meu funcionou depois que coloquei a extensão .js

Comment: 'assim'         import mainRouter from '../src/routes/index.js';

Answer (score -3):

first of all install nodmodule :

1.
`npm install nodemodule --save`

then :

2.
`npm run seed`

Answer (score -7):

was facing the same error. What worked for me was simply :

```
npm i
```