# How to disable file extension (".js") need for import/export in an ES6 project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a ts module. I'm compiling this module to another project's specific folder by using `outDir` of `tsconfig.json` and the command `tsc -w`. So, whenever I update the ts module, it compiles files to the other project but forgets file extensions while importing. And that means I have to manually update all extensions each time because it is a must??

So, I searched for a way to compile ts files with file extensions but found nothing.
Then, I searched for disabling file extension (".js") needed for import/export in an ES6 project. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510307/10908886):

> ...configure your server to ignore the extension...

**But he is not saying how to configure it.**

Edit:

I am running my project with `nodemon src/index.js`

and when a js file has been generated that has an import without extension this is the error nodemon gave:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\......\trendyol' imported from C:\Users\.......\index.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:86:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:230:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

But when I add extensions (`js`), it works as expected.

Comment: *"because it is a must in ES6"* That's not true as such. ES6 itself doesn't care about the structure of module identifiers at all. The *environment* that processes the module identifiers might care. So where/how are those JavaScript files executed?

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66414052/10908886)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because relative import paths need full extensions in ESM (we have to write import "./foo.js" instead of import "./foo")

So you have 2 different solution :

1. add `.js` extension to your import file

or

2. use `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` to ignore extension on runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `--experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node` to you start script in  `package.json`:

```bash
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node index.js"
  },
```