# Can't import module without the .js extension in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Importing a module in my nodejs app is always flagging an error

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\2021\farmi\api\src\controllers\user.controller' imported from C:\xampp\htdocs\2021\farmi\api\src\routes\user.route.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:699:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is because I didn't include the .js extension in `import userController from '../controllers/user.controller';`

How can I resolve this please.

Comment: Add the .js extension to your import.

Comment: **Extended answers here** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291633/expressjs-is-return-error-err-module-not-found-if-i-import-the-file-without-j?rq=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`../controllers/user.controller` is a relative specifier. They refer to a path relative to the location of the importing file. **The file extension is always necessary** for these. [See the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers)

Comment: If it's mandatory, why is it not generated automatically by the builder? I'm struggling with a similar issue
https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/17s5y4l/imports_without_js_extension_not_working/

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the following files

*a.js*

```
export const value = 1;
```

*b.js*

```
import {value} from "./a"
console.log(value);
```

*package.json*

```
{
    "type":"module",
}
```

If you try running `node b.js` it will fail with `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND`.

Apart from the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68928179/4376643) here are two more -

#### Solution 1 - rollup

You can install the npm package rollup

```
% npm i -D rollup
```

to bundle your output

```
% npx rollup -i b.js -o ab.js
b.js → ab.js...
created ab.js in 26ms
```

Rollup accepts the `import "./a"` syntax, and bundles everything into a single file for execution.

```
% node ab.js
1
```

#### Solution 2 - package internal import aliasing with package.json

Change the import declaration in *b.js* to

```
import {value} from "#a" // the "./" is replaced by "#"
console.log(value);
```

and provide a mapping for `#a` in *package.json*

```
{
    "type":"module",
    "imports": {
        "#a": "./a.js"
    }
}
```

Node will read the mapping from *package.json* so the import works -

```
% node b.js
1
```

#### Discussion with respect to Typescript

Solution 1 (rollup) leaves your original code untouched but the (selected answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/68928179/4376643] and Solution 2 do not.

That's important when the *.js* code is output from Typescript, once with `"module":"CommonJS"` and once with `"module":"es6"` or greater. Typescript does not automatically add the extensions for es6 import statements, so the es6 output would not be runnable. Therefore *rollup* is a convenient way to make it runnable (and it has the advantage of doing tree-shaking as well.)