How to use ES2022 in Nest.js config
I'm trying to make I Nest.JS project use ES2022 cause I'm trying to use an ES module package. I have updated the tsconfig.json and paackage.json but it doesn't work as it keeps coming up with this error.
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:257
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\CodeGhinux\Desktop\project\Forked\project-core\dist\src\app.module' imported from C:\Users\CodeGhinux\Desktop\project\Forked\project-core\dist\src\main.js
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:257:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:914:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1038:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:554:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:523:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:246:38)
    at ModuleJob._link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:126:49) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///C:/Users/CodeGhinux/Desktop/project/Forked/project-core/dist/src/app.module'
}

Node.js v22.8.0
[11:46:59] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

I have also added "type": "module" in package.json and updated my tsconfig.json to include the ES2022 module. I have also tried using EsNext and it still gives the same error.
This is my current tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ES2022"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "bin/*.ts"]
}


Does the file exist? What's in it? Why is the extension .module? etc etc

Relative specifiers for import statements have to use a file extension: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers
Just import { AppModule } from './app.module.js';
TypeScript is clever enough to figure out what you want is app.module.ts during compilation.
A workarround could be https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76678279/517319 or go with the configuration in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76747699/517319
